# Issue with converting HTML to PDF in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I have a html template where I want to convert it into PDF and then attach it with an email in asp.net core. I have use **iSharpText** to generate PDF. I have tried below code. The code successfully generate the pdf and attach with the email but when download the file and view it it's a blank page. No content is rendered.

```
            string toEmail = data.Email;
            const string subject = "Account created successfully";
            string message = $"Some message";

            TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(this.GetPdfParagraph());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
            doc.Open();
            htmlWorker.StartDocument();
            htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);
            htmlWorker.EndDocument();
            htmlWorker.Close();
            pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
            doc.Close();
            ms.Position = 0;
```

This is where I prepare the MemoryStream. After then mailing process will happen

```
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
        mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Some Txt", FromEmail));
        mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(name ?? "Some Txt", toEmail));
        mimeMessage.Subject = subject;



        BodyBuilder emailBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
        emailBuilder.HtmlBody = message;
        emailBuilder.Attachments.Add("PDFMailCheckAnother.pdf", ms);
        mimeMessage.Body = emailBuilder.ToMessageBody();

// SENDING MAIL PROCESS GOES HERE
```

This is how I have prepare my HTML templates.

```
private string GetPdfParagraph()
    {
        string paragraph = "<div style=\"border: 2px solid black; width: 100%; height: 100%;\">\n" +
        "    <div\n" +
        "        style=\"width: 48.5%; height: 96.8%; border: 2px solid black; float: left; margin-top: -2px; margin-left: -2px; padding: 10px;\">\n" +
        "        <div style=\"width: 100%;\">\n" +
        "            <div style=\"width: 33.33%; float: left;\">\n" +
        "                <b>Image</b>\n" +
        "            </div>\n" +
        "            <div style=\"width: 33.33%; float: left; text-align: center;\">\n" +
        "                <b>लगानी</b><br />\n" +
        "                <b>योजना - २०७६</b><br />\n" +
        "                <b>स्थापित</b><br />\n" +
        "                <b>शाखा (००१)</b><br />\n" +
        "            </div>\n" +
        "            <div style=\"width: 33.33%; float: left;\">\n" +
        "                <b>QR</b>\n" +
        "            </div>\n" +
        "        </div>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</div>";



        return paragraph;
    }
```

How do I solve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: it looks like the HTML is invalid - missed *</div>*.